# Get my Current Location in Tabbed Fragement

Tags: android, location, android-location, gmsmapview

I have three swipeable tabs. With each tab being a Fragment. The first fragment displays an image. The Second Fragment is supposed to get the users location and display it on a map. I use a SupportMapFragment in the layout of the second fragment see the xml that follows: fragement_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/current_location"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
       />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My code for the fragment is as follows:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private View view;

    private  SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    public MapFragment ()
     {

     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
       init();
       return view;
    }

    private void init() {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.current_location);
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        }
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(onMyLocationButtonClickListener);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(onMyLocationClickListener);
        enableMyLocationIfPermitted();

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(11);
    }


    private void enableMyLocationIfPermitted() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void showDefaultLocation() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Location permission not granted, " +
                        "showing default location",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng redmond = new LatLng(-33.98827,  25.64636);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(redmond));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    enableMyLocationIfPermitted();
                } else {
                    showDefaultLocation();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener onMyLocationButtonClickListener =
            new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(15);
                    return false;
                }
            };

    private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener onMyLocationClickListener =
            new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {

                    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(12);

                    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
                    circleOptions.center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                            location.getLongitude()));

                    circleOptions.radius(200);
                    circleOptions.fillColor(Color.RED);
                    circleOptions.strokeWidth(6);

                    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
                }
            };

}
```

The activity that holds the fragments code is below:

```
public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    //This is our viewPager
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    String[] tabTitle={"Image","Your Location","Sign Out"};

    ImageFragment imageFragment;
    MapFragment mapFragment;
    LogOutFragment logOutFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);


        //Initializing the tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {




        if(activeNetwork())
        {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            imageFragment = new ImageFragment();
            mapFragment = new MapFragment();
            logOutFragment = new LogOutFragment();
            adapter.addFragment(imageFragment, "Image");
            adapter.addFragment(mapFragment, "Map");
            adapter.addFragment(logOutFragment, "Logout");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }

    public boolean activeNetwork () {

        // TODO: Not the most efficient method but will do for this context

        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnected();

        return isConnected;

    }
}
```

The current problem that I am facing is that the map is displayed. However, the Google OnMyLocationButtonClickListener button is not displayed and the current view below is displayed and my current location is not displayed

[image: The Map View Displayed]

I want the map to display like the image below [image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve the issue see the below code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
{
    private View view;
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    public static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 100;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    public MapFragment()
    {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Your Location");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else
            {
                //Request Location Permission to user
                checkPermission();
            }
        } else
        {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void checkPermission()
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this.getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                            {

                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapFragment.this.getActivity(),
                                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else
            {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(),
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
            {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(),
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
                        {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "permission denied by user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Location");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        //move map camera and we can also set zoom level
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));

    }
```